# Voxelizing in three.js — particle materials from Textures

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have an image that I am mapping to a `PlaneGeometry` using the `TextureLoader#load()` — it renders nicely ***as long as my camera is not looking "along" the plane***, in which case it (of course) is of zero-width, and disappears from view.

I'm trying to figure out how to give the image some *depth*, so my current ideas are:

- Generate a `ParticleSystem` where the particle at `(x, y)` shares its color with the (greyscale) pixel in the image at `(x, y)` — effectively, making each pixel a camera-facing billboard
- "Cube-ifying" each pixel in the image so it takes up some space in the `z` direction. So a pixel at `(x, y)` becomes a cube at `(x, y, z)` with some size in all three dimensions.

Both allow me to look 'along' the edge of the image and see *something*, whereas the plane is invisible.

My first question is, is this *possible*, and second, what is the *name* for this voxelization technique? Is it natively supported in three.js?

Very happy to provide more info or some basic code if that's at all helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definite possible.

The idea with the cubes should be doable in every decent 3d-engine.
Its just a matter of cloning / instancing cubes, and than position and color them accordingly.

Not sure if there is a name for this technique.

Also not sure about particle-systems in threejs, but i suppose that would be a option too.

My real answer is this: Use Heightmaps

They kind of do exactly what you want. A heightmap is a greyscale texture, and for each verticle of the geometry it is mapped on, it will offset the y-component of the verticles positions according to the grayscale (white = no offset, black = full offset)
http://danni-three.blogspot.de/2013/09/threejs-heightmaps.html

Comment: Heightmaps are *close*, but don't extrude everything equally. What I'm looking for is an 'ice cube tray' where each pixel is extruded equally into a cube: A heightmap would make the greyscale image look more like a mountainous landscape. But.... definitely food for thought...

Comment: Well, I see your point, but just cloning a cube per pixel might not give you the result you are after performance wise.  Of course this will depent on your image size and the power of the device used to view the stuff. You might want to consider slicing your image into small portions  (like 5px X 5px) and than texture each cube with its own small textures. Or alternative you could use only 1 texture, but set the uv values of the cube so that every cube displays a part of the image. With either ways I think you will get better results than just using 1 cube per px.

Comment: Just slogged through some really awful code to generate a cube per pixel — completely right. One tiny image is enough to cripple my laptop... My understanding is that a ParticleSystem wouldn't suffer from the same performance issues as a collection of meshes, but I may see if I can cheat with a heightmap...

Comment: I think if your scene is static, the best option performance wise will be to not use multiple meshes, but build the complete geometry using 1 mesh. Threejs is rendering on gpu, and in general it is cheaper to render 1 big mesh, than to render multiple smaller meshes. This would bring the restcrition that you have to do the coloring either using uv-values to map to the image, or to use vertex-colors.